# calling methods from objects (Java)

Tags: java, object, methods

I'm new(ish) to java and I'm making a program for fun that allows you to create different users, login to those users, and make notes. I'm stuck on the user creation part. There is this one line of code that won't work. I have an array called `userarr` that holds user objects. Inside the object is the user creation method. This is the line of code that takes the variables you type in for the username and password and plugs it into the usercreation method:

```
userarr[userarr.length+1] = new user.usercreation(username,password);
```

It says it can't find `usercreation` method inside the class. But I don't know how to use the `usercreation` method outside the object and be able to create different named objects.

Here is the entire class:

```
public class TextGame {

    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    class user extends TextGame {
        String username;
        int password;
        String[] notes;
        public void usercreation(String username, int password) {
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;
        }
        public void login(int password) {
            this.password = password;
            System.out.println("please type the password to proceed.");
            if (scan.nextLine().equals(this.password)) {
                System.out.println("logged in. type 'note' to access notes, or 'logoff' to log off this user.");
            }
        }

    }
    static user[] userarr;

    public static void newuser() {
        System.out.println("\n\nType the username for this user.");
        String username = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Username is now " + username + ". is this what you want? type 'yes' to proceed, or 'no' to enter username again.");
        if (scan.nextLine().equals("no")) {
            newuser();
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("\n\n type the password for this user. (numbers only.)");
            int password = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("user is " + username + " and password is " + password + " is this what you want?");
            if (scan.nextLine().equals("no")) {
                newuser();
            } else {
                userarr[userarr.length + 1] = new user.usercreation(username, password);

            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to LINCOLN COMP console OS. Type 'new' to create a new user, type 'log' to log in to an existing user, or type 'exit' to leave.\nif you are asked a yes or no question, if you type something ether than yes or no, it will default to yes.");
        String ch1 = scan.nextLine();
        switch (ch1) {
        case "new":
            System.out.println("Initializing user creation method:");
            newuser();
            break;
        case "log":

            break;
        case "exit":
            System.out.println("Goodbye!");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `userarr[userarr.length+1] = new user().usercreation(username,password);`? - but `usercreation` returns `void`

Comment: You might also want to take a look at [Code Conventions for Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make your code easier to read by others and it easier for you to read others

Comment: `usercreation()` returns `void`, so it'll still fail, just differently.  I think the method should be replaced with a constructor, now that I look at it a bit more.

Comment: you didn't create an object of the "userarr" yet. you've just declared it.

Comment: If you have never heard of Object Oriented Programming you should take a look at it while learning Java with the official tutorials at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so starting with `new user.usercreation(username,password);`

1. `usercreation` is not a static inner class of `user`, so you can't create it
2. `usercreation` is a method of `user` which returns `void`, so you returns nothing, so you can't assign it to anything.

## You could...

Create the instance of user, apply the properties and assign it to the array as separate actions

```
user newUser = user();
newUser.usercreation(username,password);
userarr[userarr.length+1] = newUser;
```

Equally, you could make `usercreation` a factory methhod, but I'm trying to keep it simply.

## You could...

Based on what you seem to be trying to do, is make the `usercreation` method into a class constructor, which would make more sense...

```
class user extends TextGame {
    String username;
    int password;
    String[] notes;
    
    public user(String username, int password) {
        this.username=username;
        this.password=password;
    }

    public void login(int password) {
        this.password=password;
        System.out.println("please type the password to proceed.");
        if (scan.nextLine().equals(this.password)) {
            System.out.println("logged in. type 'note' to access notes, or 'logoff' to log off this user.");
        }
    }

}
```

Then you could just do...

```
userarr[userarr.length+1] = new user(username,password);
```

You're also haven't create an instance of the `userarr`, so you're going to hit a `NullPointerException`

You should do something like...

```
userarr = new user[10];
```

before you try and use it.

This will allow you to maintain ten instances of the `user` class.  You should also check to ensure that you've not exceeded the number of available elements in the array before you try and add new elements.

Have a look at the [Arrays Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) for more details

I'd encourage you to have a look at [Code Conventions for Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html), which make it easier for other people to read your code and make it easier for you to read others

Comment: If I had to cover EVERYTHING that was wrong with the code, I'd have written a "beginner's guide to programming in Java" tutorial :P - I have "now" updated it to include those points and directions to the Java tutorials, hopefully, that'll be enough for now :P

Comment: Certainly agree.

Comment: so i did this, as the other answers said i should do. but it still wont work. the problem is: non static variable this doesnt work or something like that. i updated everything as you said

Comment: @lincolnpepper Okay, because 1- You're using `static` methods and 2- You've defined `user` as a inner class, in order to reference it from a `static` context, you need to define it as `static` ... :P ... `static class user extends TextGame {`

Answer (score 0):

Before you use the usercreation method from a different class, you must first instantiate an object of usercreation class to gain access to it's properties(methods, variables) in a different class.

Example:

UserCreation us = new UserCreation (default constructor parameters);

userarr[userarr.length+1] = us.usercreation(username,password);

Comment: It would fail even if it were instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'd like to state that you haven't `instantiated` the `userarr` array yet. So, I recommend to do that first.

Secondly,`new user.usercreation(username,password);`  `usercreation` is not a static inner class of `user`, so you can't create it.

Thirdly, `usercreation` is a method which returns void in which case you can't assign it to anything.

it seems that you want to invoke this method:

```
public void usercreation(String username, int password) {
      this.username=username;
      this.password=password;
}
```

In order to invoke that method, you must create an `object` of type `user` first in order to invoke it.

**Example:**

```
user user1 =  new user();
user1.usercreation(username,password);
userarr[userarr.length+1] = user1;
```

However, the easiest way would be to make a `constructor` to initialise the `username` and `password` like below:

```
public user(String username, int password) {
      this.username=username;
      this.password=password;
}
```

Hence you can easily do this:

```
userarr[userarr.length+1] = new user(username,password);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really be using a constructor:

```
public user(String username, int password) { // should be named User
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}
```

Then you could add a user to an array like so:

```
userarr[userarr.length+1] = new User("username", 1); // doesn't work!
```

...Except, this code will fail because you didn't instantiate the array. And even if you had, you can't assign an element to an array like this. Arrays do not automatically re-size themselves, so when you try to add an element like this you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and your program will exit.